# Canno add values to database by javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, heidisql

I am getting an error on node.js, and I cannot identify why. Can anybody help me? If I add only 1 data from the array it gets added to the database. However, when I add other inputs, it displays an error in node.js and doesn't get saved in my database.

[image: node.js error]

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/register/*', handleGetRequest); //how do I pass usrName here?
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(5000);

function handleGetRequest(request, response){
var pathArray = request.url.split("/");
var pathEnd = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
if(pathEnd === 'register'){
    response.send("{working}");
    //console.log(request.body.usrName);
}
else
    var registerArray = pathEnd.split("&");

    response.send(JSON.stringify(registerArray));
    saveToDb(registerArray);
   // response.send("{error: 'Path not recognized'}");
}

function saveToDb(registerArray){
    for (var i = 0; i < registerArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(registerArray[i]);
    }
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'customer',
    port: 6000
});
con.connect();
addData();
function addData(){
    var query = con.query(
        "INSERT INTO cust (id,LastName,FirstName) VALUES 
('001,"+registerArray[0]+"," +registerArray[1]+"');",function(err, result, 
 fields){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('results' , result);
        }
    );
}
//Close the connection
con.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quotes in your SQL statement that cause the problem. The code should look like this:

```
function addData(){
    var query = con.query(
        "INSERT INTO cust (id,LastName,FirstName) VALUES 
        ('001','"+registerArray[0]+"','" +registerArray[1]+"');",
        function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('results' , result);
        }
    );
}
```